# AWS cloudformation for batch stuck in review_in_progress

Tags: makefile, aws-cloudformation, aws-batch

I have the following aws cli code in my project's makefile trying to deploy my troposphere cf template:

```html
aws cloudformation deploy \
        --template-file params/batch.json \
        --stack-name $(STACK_NAME) \
        --parameter-overrides file://params/$(ENV).json \
        --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM \
        --output json && \
    aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete \
        --stack-name $(STACK_NAME)
```

I am trying to wait for the template to complete and deploy. Even so, it gets stuck in review_in_progress. Not sure if it is just a template issue or I also have to execute the changeset as I am only creating it.

Comment: What is your template?